# Connection to AWS database gives back "You may not specify an IPv4 CIDR for an existing referenced group id rule."

Tags: postgresql, aws

I try to connect to an AWS database instance from a client by following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/simplebackups/allow-a-remote-ip-to-connect-to-your-amazon-rds-mysql-instance-2d5074d601eb

I looked for my own IP and pasted it into "Source" as suggested by the website. However, there is an error below. Could some of you help me to understand it?

*You may not specify an IPv4 CIDR for an existing referenced group id rule*.

Best regards,
Bruno P.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the drop down of MyIp, then clicked on the box next to it, and did security group, and it allowed me to select default security group